# Element wise dot product and einsum

Tags: python, numpy

i'm having this problem:

```
C = np.random.random((10, 10000, 100))
B = np.random.random((10, 10000, 100))
D1 = np.einsum("ikj,ijt->ikt", C.transpose(0, 2, 1), B)
D2 = np.array([np.dot(C[k].T, B[k]) for k in range(10)])
```

And it happens to be different things. Could you please explain me why?

Comment: Did you try np.allclose(D1, D2)? or what are you referring to?

Comment: `np.allclose(...)` returns `True` for this code. So, D1 is equal to D2 .